# Programming in C, Using pow function

Tags: c, precision, pow

This is a part of code I wrote in a C program---

```
else if((pow(b,2.0)-4*a*c)>0) {
    printf("\nRoots=%.2f and %.2f\n",
           (-b+pow(b*b-4*a*c,0.5))/(2*a),
           (-b-pow(b*b-4*a*c,0.5))/(2*a));
} else
    printf("\nBoth roots are %.2f\n",-b/(2*a));
```

In the console, if I write `a` as `1`, `b` as `14` and `c` as `49`, If says "Roots =-7.00 and -7.00" ... instead of saying "Both roots are -7.00" But it shows latter result if I replace `pow(b,2)` by `b*b` in `else if` condition.... Why is this so? Please explain.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your posts are better readable if you edit them and formnat them properly.

Comment: Is it really necessary to calculate the determinant three times?

Comment: Please explaln why you did not break up this equation solving into smaller chunks, with termp vars, so allowing you to inspect the var values and investigate this issue by yourself?

Comment: I have your expected result on my machine (Ubuntu 14.04 - gcc 4.8.4)

Comment: Yes, another good point - which compiler did you use?

Comment: @Martin James: you meant discriminant, not determinant. :-)

Comment: ^^ I only just got up and I've only had one coffee:((

Comment: It's the Matrix trying to tell you not to use `pow` *or* floating point equality...

Comment: OP - which compiler and version??

Comment: ..at least tell us the compiler name and/or url if online.....

Comment: ..................[tumbleweed]....................

Comment: @Martin James I am using GNU GCC Compiler.. Sorry for late reply.

Answer (score 3):

Please include a minimum working example with your code.

Anyway, it works on my system (Debian GNU/Linux testing, gcc 5.2.1):

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {

    float a,b,c;
    scanf("%f",&a);
    scanf("%f",&b);
    scanf("%f",&c);

    if ((pow(b,2.0)-4*a*c)<0)
        printf("\nNo roots!\n");
    else if((pow(b,2.0)-4*a*c)>0) {
        printf("\nRoots=%.2f and %.2f\n",
               (-b+pow(b*b-4*a*c,0.5))/(2*a),
               (-b-pow(b*b-4*a*c,0.5))/(2*a));
    } else
        printf("\nBoth roots are %.2f\n",-b/(2*a));
    return 0;
}
```

If I enter 1, 14, 49, the program answers `Both roots are -7.0`. But this *may* vary among systems, because you are using floating point arithmetic and I don't know how your `pow()` function was implemented. Not all real numbers can be represented on a computer -- here's a good description of how it works for [single precision floats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format). And each compiler/runtime environment will have a possibly different implementation of the math library (which includes `pow`, that you have used).

So, I would avoid `pow` at all if possible. Use `b*b` instead, and save `pow` for when you really need it. And as Tom Karzes mentioned, `sqrt` is also better than using `pow` for calculating square roots.

One last thing: calculating the discriminant only once would make your program more readable:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    float a,b,c;
    float delta;
    scanf("%f",&a);
    scanf("%f",&b);
    scanf("%f",&c);

    delta = b*b-4*a*c;

    if (delta<0)
        printf("\nNo roots!\n");
    else if(delta>0)
        printf("\nRoots=%.2f and %.2f\n",
               (-b+sqrt(delta))/(2*a),
               (-b-sqrt(delta))/(2*a));
    else
        printf("\nBoth roots are %.2f\n",-b/(2*a));
    return 0;
}
```

One more thing you may try is to use `double` instead of `float`, so you'll have more precision (not relevant depending on the numbers you'll be using, but it's a good idea to use `doubles` if you don't have huge matrices of numbers that could take too much memory -- a `double` takes twice as memory as a `float` to represent).

Comment: Using `float` instead of `double` is pushing for more precision issues.

Comment: @chqrlie: yes, I used `float` because I was trying to reproduce the OP's result. But even with `float`, the program worked. :-)

Answer (score 2):

This probably a precision issue.  The algorithm used by `pow(b, 2.0)` for `b` positive could be something like `exp(2.0 * log(b))` and may produce a number that is very close to `196.0` but not exactly `196`.  The comparison fails but the results still look the same when rounded to 2 decimal places for printing.  Try `%g` instead.

Conversely `b * b` for `b = 14.0` computes exactly as `196`.

Incidentally, I get the proper result for your code on my laptop, what OS and compiler do you use?

Comment: Yes, I too would like to know OS and compiler.

Comment: @MartinJames: Compiling with `clang` on OS/X. if I use `exp(log(b)*2.0)`, I get a very small floating point value and the program says there are no roots `;-)`.  Definitely not a good idea to use math functions for this.

Comment: OH, I'm sure that YOU compiled/linked/tested it.  The thing is, the longer this goes on, the more I get this feeling that that the OP did not:(

Comment: @MartinJames I am using Windows 10 pro and GNU GCC compiler .... Sorry for late reply ...

Comment: @AkhilRaj: do you know which C library you link to?  The code would also depend on the optimisation settings and some other flags controlling floating point code generation.  What are your commands for compiling and linking?  Also edit your post to show the rest of the function, with the definitions of all variables.

Answer (score 2):

Using `pow(b, 2.0)` will generally be less accurate than `b*b`.  While they're mathematically the same, the `pow` function is going to do something like `exp(2.0 * log(b))`.  It also needs to make special checks for negative `b` etc.  Also, when taking the square root, use `sqrt(x)` rather than `pow(x, 0.5)`, for similar reasons:  It will be faster and more accurate.

Your code will also be improved by computing the discriminant once and saving it rather than replicating the code.

Comment: Better save the discriminant as a `double` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

This article would guide you why the results differ : https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2013/07/16/floating-point-determinism/

I would suggest if you try this and see if that works.

```
((int)pow(b,2) - (4*a*c))>0 // Assuming computation is based on integers.
```

If not, try these suggestions (with analogous functions in C):

[What is the best way to compare floats for almost-equality in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595425/what-is-the-best-way-to-compare-floats-for-almost-equality-in-python)